# Coda 2 publish button not working

Tags: coda

I have exactly the same site settings in coda 1.7.4 as I do in coda 2 but when I click the publish arrow in coda 2 it tells me "Set both local and Remote paths in a site to publish your changes".
I have already done that but it still is not working. As I said the same settings are in the older version and it works fine and publishes.

Anyone have any of the same problems.

Comment: Anyone out there having the same issue. 5 days later and I still can't get this to work??? Please anyone

Answer (score 35):

I contacted Coda support for exactly this issue today... Same as you, after setting up a site with the correct remote and local roots - confirmed because I could connect to both - but still the publish window said "Set both local and Remote paths in a site to publish your changes".

Literally **the solution was to close Coda down and re-open it**. Apparently this is a known issue, when setting up a new site you have to restart Coda to use the publish functionality.

Just by closing Coda and restarting it the publish function now works for me.

Comment: Seven months later and one still has to restart Coda. v2.0.11.

Comment: @BenLeah You solved the issue.  I wasted several days on this waiting for a support answer from Panic.  Thanks. Still broken in 2.0.13.

Comment: April 2014. Version 2.0.13. Still not fixed. Let's see what they have to say for themselves https://twitter.com/TomCaflisch/status/457022731628720128

Comment: September 2014. Version 2.0.14. Still not fixed.

Answer (score 8):

I had this problem and none of the above worked. I got the following reply from the team at Coda and it worked a treat.

1. Right click the saved site in question and choose Edit. Disable publishing and automatic indexing.
2. Save and close the site
3. Open the site, then from the menubar choose File > Sites > Rebuild Site Index
4. After the indexing competes, restart Coda and then re-enable publishing (and optionally, automatic indexing)

Comment: In 2018, this is still the solution that works when publishing stops working.

Comment: I second that, I just managed to get my publishing functionality to work again using the procedure described here. Coda 2.6.10

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue until I ticked the "Use Publishing" in the site settings.
Check out the image: [CODA 2 Site Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Is4En.jpg)

I can now publish via the ⌥⌘P on a Mac.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! I had forgotten about step 1.

Answer (score 1):

It's unbelievable that Panic has not fixed this by now.

Finding and deleting every Coda related file and reinstalling Coda did not help.

My "fix" (this time) was to delete the site in Coda and recreate it.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically, you have to close all the open documents in Coda, reconfirm the local and remote directories configured for the site, then close Coda2 and reopen it.

Honestly, that a bug like this still exists, is amazing. After all these years, I still need to keep Dreamweaver around. Get with it Coda! #coda #coda2

Answer (score 0):

My "fix" (this time) was:

- to edit the FTP server's domain to be not working,
- open the site,
- let it complain the server is wrong,
- close Coda,
- reopen Coda,
- fix FTP domain,
- open site,

and voilà!

A classic I-learn-by-complaining case. ;-)

(Coda 2.6.10...)

Answer (score 0):

I had a situation where the publishing had been working ok, and then mysteriously stopped.

I tried all the suggestions previously answered by BenLeah, Ben Darlington, Robert Barrueco, and Manu, and upgraded to the latest version of Coda2 (from 2.6.9 to 2.6.10), but none of these restored publishing.

What did finally work for me, was to physically delete the site connection panel in Coda2 and create a new site altogether (with the exact same settings). Not sure if this will work again if the publishing turns itself off again in the future, or if it solves the problem for anybody else. If it ever does, I'll update this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Publish stopped working for one of my sites, but for entirely different reasons than others have discussed here. I used Time Machine to roll back to a recent version of the site, renaming the original folder so I would know not to use it. Coda 2, however, kept pointing to the original (renamed) folder.

So it seems Coda uses a unique ID to identify the local root folder, not a simple file path. This is probably a good idea in most cases—it means if you move or change the name of this folder in the Finder, Coda still knows where it is. But if the actual folder changes (as it will if you recover from a backup), you can expect the unexpected.

I still don't know why the publish feature stopped working with the renamed folder. (In some ways I'm glad it did, as it stopped me publishing from the wrong folder.) All I know is that updating the 'Local Root' of the site fixed the problem.

Answer (score -2):

You have to set the FTP putting the mouse on the file between your site and the page. Below the menu, as soon as you click file you will open in the middle a screen. Then you put in your FTP settings.

Comment: It's not polite to hold the capslock key down on the internet.

Comment: @Ben the letters FTP are actually an acronym, his usage of capital letters here is correct.

Comment: Look at [the previous revision](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16307100/revisions) before my edit @Dylan.